# My referral traffic is showing a "shared hosting domain/url" instead of the normal URL? Why?

Tags: referrer

I am running a website using HTTPS and while reviewing the visitor logs I noticed that a referral I made for testing is coming up as "serverxxx.web-hosting.com" instead of as the full domain name. Why?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by "full domain name" (and what is a domain name not full?), but `serverxxx.web-hosting.com` is a perfectly valid domain name, as any other. It depends on lot of things, but when a webserver puts in its logging an IP address and optionally a name as reverse resolution of the IP (if that is what you meant), that resolution is made using `PTR` records, which won't typically contain website names (consider that any given IP address can host dozens, hundreds or thousands of websites...)

Comment: @watchy while posting the question you would have been asked to provide a detailed question, provide as much information as possible and steps you had taken to solve the problem. Images(screenshots), part of code please include if needed and possible